# how to disableedit in column of nggrid?

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I am trying to disable to celledit for a column in a nggrid:

```
$scope.gridOptions = { 
  data: 'myData', 
  enableCellSelection: true,
  enableCellEditOnFocus:true,
  enableRowSelection: false,
  columnDefs: [{field: 'name', displayName: 'Name', enableCellEdit: true}, 
  {field:'age', displayName:'Age',
  cellTemplate: '<div ng-disabled=true ng-class="{green: row.getProperty(col.field) == row.getProperty(\'name\'),red:row.getProperty(col.field) != row.getProperty(\'name\')}"><div style="text-align:center;"                    class="ngCellText">{{row.getProperty(col.field)}}</div></div>'}]
};
```

I tried ng-disabled=true but it does not work? how to do this?
plunkr:http://plnkr.co/edit/nj57V6WcHJxN5OosvwYx?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Could you try using `enableCellEdit: false` ?

`columnDefs: [{field: 'name', displayName: 'Name', enableCellEdit: false},`